# how to use special characters like '<' or '&' in XML file generation in vb.net

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

I am passing an array to a function which converts the array to an XML. But I am not able to use special characters like `"<"` or `"&"`. When I pass these it gives error invalid XML file.

```
Protected Sub drawgraph(ByRef dt As DataTable, ByVal name As String)
    Try

        Dim n(dt.Columns.Count - 3) As String
        Dim r(dt.Columns.Count - 3) As String

        For i As Integer = 1 To dt.Columns.Count - 2
            ***n(i - 1) = dt.Columns(i).ColumnName.ToString.Replace("<", "&lt;")***

            r(i - 1) = (dt.Rows(0).Item(i))
        Next
        ChartBuilder1.BuildLabel(n)
        ChartBuilder1.BuildValues(r, "Age Profile")

        ChartBuilder1.GenerateGraph()
        ChartBuilder1.Visible = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        lbl_msg.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

I am replacing `"<"` with `"&lt;"` but it is not working

Comment: Why are you trying to build XML yourself, instead of using an XML API? And why are you passing `dt` by reference when you never change the value of it?

Comment: i am using a chat builder control with generates xml. i am using byref to save space

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what `ByRef` does. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html - it's a C#-based article, but VB works the same way. You haven't really told us enough about the "chat builder control" to answer your question.

Comment: chart builder control builds charts based on the input as array we provide to it. I am drawing a pie chart based on the values in my array n and r. chart builder control generates the XML based on my array and then populates chart(Fusion chart).

Comment: Sounds like this is a bug in the "chart builder control". You may have to work round the bug.

Comment: @makkJ i too think so. I will check it out and let you know.

Answer (score 7):

Use HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode to "escape" the special characters.

"<" becomes `&lt;`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/w3te6wfz.aspx

Comment: I got the answer. USe %26 instead of & in entity reference. for example: '<' = %26lt;
'>' = %26gt;
'&' = %26amp;