# How to show/generate the special character "&" in xml file?

Tags: java, xml, apache-poi

I have a spreadsheet like this:

[image]

It contains a special character "&". After I converted it to xml, it's rendered as an entity name [image].

Here is the xml:

[image]

How to show/generate the special character "&" in xml file?

Thanks very much

Comment: Why you want to do that.? (Just being curios)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use special characters like '<' or '&' in XML file generation in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580672/how-to-use-special-characters-like-or-in-xml-file-generation-in-vb-net)

Comment: The way to do it is exactly the way you have done it, by using the `&amp;` entity reference. So what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have the & sign in XML. It's not a properly formatted XML - that's why it's replaced with the & symbol.

Another option you have is using CDATA like this:

```
<![CDATA[SAILOR T&T]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a detail description of predefined entity of XML in http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp.

[image]